# How can I update included table in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I using this code and I need to update data in the same code. I know I can get data with the same query but I like to do it by this code.

How can I do that?

```
List<TblUserCity> removedUserCityData = new List<TblUserCity>();
var removedUserCities = userData
    .TblUserCities
    .Where(x => !cityIdList.Contains(x.TblCityId))
    .ToList();

if (removedUserCities.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var cityItem in removedUserCities)
    {
        cityItem.RemoveDate = DateTime.Now;
        removedUserCityData.Add(cityItem);
    }
    _db.TblUserCities.UpdateRange(removedUserCityData);
}
```